# Replacing dynamic % width with scaleX + translateX

Tags: css

I am currently transitioning the `width` property of an element. I would like to replace this with transitions on `scaleX` and `translateX` for better rendering performance.

I'm struggling to come up with a proper 1:1 conversion between the two concepts.

Below is a box which contains two lines. Each line has a bar inside of it. The first bar is created using `width`. The second bar is created using `scaleX` and `translateX`. The second bar breaks out of the box. It should appear identical to the `width` bar for all possible values.

Is this an appropriate way to tackle this problem? If not, how should I approach it? If so, I have some concerns:

- I feel like I shouldn't have to use 1% width. I thought I could say 1px and scale that, but maybe that isn't the right idea.
- I'm unclear if I should use 1% width and scale up, or 100% width and scale down. Perhaps they're equivalent, but the width of the bar controls the positioning of `translateX`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.line {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
.bar {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.bar.width {
  width: 66.6%;
}
.bar.scale {
  width: 1%;
  transform: scaleX(66.6) translateX(33%);
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='line'>
    <div class='bar width'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='line'>
    <div class='bar scale'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler than all that.  You're already scaling the element to 66%.  Now all you need to do is set the origin to the far left of the element with `transform-origin: 0 50%;` and drop the translate rule.  That should fix the issue.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.line {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
.bar {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.bar.width {
  width: 66.6%;
}
.bar.scale {
  width: 1%;
  transform: scaleX(66.6);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='line'>
    <div class='bar width'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='line'>
    <div class='bar scale'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Transform-origin! Of course. Thank you. I feel silly now.

Edit: Although it appears that my usage of 1% is still throwing the math off near the end.  Adjusting it to 100% and scaleX(.666) works fine.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad I could help.  One thing I did notice, however, is that it's not a perfect translation from the old method to the new.  It does have a slight discrepancy in my browser probably because it's trying to multiply 1% by 66.6 rather than making it true 66.6% of the parent.  You may still have to use overflow as @drinchev suggests in his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30788066/854246.  EDIT:  oops.  It was deleted.  but basically, you may experience overflow issues due to rounding.

Comment: Yeah it looks like we discovered that at the same time, but browser is much happier with 100% + scaled down, no rounding issues.